# Angular 4 how to populate a variable from a method call inside ng-template

Tags: angular, ng-template

I'm creating a calendar component that constructs a calendar (month view) for a given date.  I've created a custom ng-template to pass into calendar control so I can inject custom content for each day in the calendar, based on data being returned from a service call.  Here's my code:

```
<section class="calendar-container" *ngIf="inventoryService.InventoryAvailableListStream | async; let InventoryList">
    <app-calendar [dayTemplate]="myCustomDayTemplate"></app-calendar>

    <ng-template #myCustomDayTemplate let-day="day">
        <span class="inventory-level" [ngClass]="{'no-inventory': (getValueByDay(InventoryList, day) === 0)}">
            {{getValueByDay(InventoryList, day)}}           
        </span>
    </ng-template>  
</section>
```

I have a section that displays once my inventoryService stream is populated with values from server into a variable called 'InventoryList'.  In my custom ng-template (#myCustomDayTemplate), I'm passing 'day' variable into this template based on processing in app-calendar.  Inside my custom template, I call getValueByDay that looks into InventoryList for the given day and surfaces an inventory count.  This is all working, but I need to be able to change the style of the inventory value surfaced to the UI if the inventory value is 0.

I can achieve this by calling getValueByDay twice (once to surface the value to the UI and once to determine ngClass' 'no-inventory').  Is it possible to call getValueByDay once and place the answer into a variable then use that variable in the UI as well as to determine ngClass' 'no-inventory'?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you add the code for `getValueByDay` method in your ts file

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method once and update a variable in the component for `ngClass` as below,

```
<ng-template #myCustomDayTemplate let-day="day">
    <span class="inventory-level" [ngClass]="{'no-inventory': isZeroInventory}">
        {{getValueByDay(InventoryList, day)}}           
    </span>
</ng-template>
```

Declare a variable like

```
isZeroInventory : boolean = false;
```

The method should contain logics and update the above variable as below,

```
getValueByDay(inventoryList,day){
 // logics 
   this.isZeroInventory = true/false;
}
```

Comment: myCustomDayTemplate and getValueByDay gets called for every single day in the calendar.  Wouldn't this.isZeroInventory be overwritten and not be specific to a given day?

Comment: what are the properties present inside `InventoryList`

Comment: Inventory List just contains Date and Count.  I suppose I can augment that with isZeroInventory

Comment: what you mean by this `augment`. Also what is the logic behind the `getValueByDay()` method

Comment: the logic in getValueByDay() just filters the InventoryList by date and surfaces the Count for that day.  By augment, I mean to add isZeroInventory as a property of each item in InventoryList .